# How to my app run forever, even in the background

Tags: java, background, speech-recognition

I made an app that has speech recognition so when I press the home button it stops recording but i want it to run in the background as well. I have tried this code but i don't know what to put in do you jobs here.

```
public class YourService extends Service {

    private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
    private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_Id";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

        // do your jobs here

        startForeground();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void startForeground() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 
                NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID) // don't forget create a notification channel first
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Service is running background")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build());         
    }
}
```

Do I have to put my entire main activity in this or what do i have to put?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use threads here. For example, I want to run an application and I want it to constantly print something in the background. It'll look something like this:

```
public class BackgroundProcess implements Runnable {

    public boolean resume;

    public void stop() {
        resume = false;
    }

    public BackgroundProcess() {
        resume = true;
    }

    // code that will be run as a thread must be inside the run() function;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(resume) {
            System.out.println("Are we there yet?");
        }
    }
}

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    BackgroundProcess bp = new BackgroundProcess();
    bp.start(); // starts the thread
    }
}
```

There are two ways in creating a thread in Java. Here's something you can read about it https://www.javatpoint.com/creating-thread

Comment: Thread can't guarantee that the app will run forever in the background.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot one thing here. I'll edit my answer.